# source for kel erech apayim in tachanun

Tags: sources-mekorot, tachanun, nusach-sefard

In nussach sefard in Tachanun after Oshamnu, is the tefillah kel erech apayim atah uva'al horachamin nikraisah.

what is the source for this tefillah ?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: It's in the Ashkenaz Yom Kippour Davening - so it probably comes from there. See https://tinyurl.com/yd8wa7f2

Comment: Considering ^^^, when you ask for the "source", are you asking about the history / who composed the piyut itself, or do you want to know why Nusach Sefard includes this in Tachanun?